# Why do we need to end a List with "Nil"

Tags: scala

Following is one of the ways to define a List in scala. Why do we need to end it with Nil?

```
val oneTwoThree = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `::` operator expects an element on the left-hand side and a list on the right-hand side.

`3` is not a list. So just `1 :: 2 :: 3` without the `:: Nil` would be a type error.

Answer (score 5):

`::` is the list prepend operator. To construct a list with this operator you must start with an existing list. The empty list, called `Nil`, is a convenient starting point.

Comment: Well, you can start with _any_ list.

Comment: True, I've changed the wording to make it clearer you could use any list.

Answer (score 1):

`Nil` is just more of an elegant way to tell us a list is empty, which is the basis of pattern matching against `List`s. To say such a way is elegant, is that `Nil` makes `List` an [algebraic data type](http://merrigrove.blogspot.com/2011/12/another-introduction-to-algebraic-data.html).

```
xs match {
  case Nil => ...
  case head :: tail => ...
}
```

It somehow can be treated as the '\0' character used in C strings to indicate the end of a string.

Comment: You mean, terribly stupid?

Comment: @Puppy, definitely not for me! I was just suggesting the necessity of `Nil`. And from the perspective of C, I don't see the '\0' idea is stupid either.

Answer (score 0):

Nil is just an object (single instance) of List that contains no elements (is empty). The pattern you've shown is one of many ways to define a List. The `::` operator associates right, so it looks for a method on the element to the right that is `::` and uses the left operand as the method argument.

An easier, and clearer, way of defining a List is this:

```scala
val oneTwoThree = List(1,2,3)
```

or if you prefer typical constructor syntax

```scala
val oneTwoThree = new List(1,2,3)
```